# How to remove $ from value before passing it as a float?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have tried several methods of removing the `$` from a column of values that looks like [$95,800.50].

I want to call `min` and `max` on a column of salaries but first I must parse it as a float but can't because of the `$`.

```
import csv
f = open("Employee_Salaries_-_2014.csv") 
rows = csv.reader(f)
next(rows)   

class employeeInfo:
    gender = ""
    salary = 0
    title = ""

employee = []

for col in rows:
    e = employeeInfo()
    e.gender = col[1]
    e.salary = col[2]
    e.title = col[9]

    employee.append(e)
```

Comment: Asking the same question again when you don't get an answer the first time is strongly frowned on here; repeat offenses can eventually result in a ban. Edit your first instance of the question to improve it, don't simply re-ask. (Once you've earned enough reputation, you can also place bounties for questions that aren't getting enough attention, but that's an earned privilege).

Comment: ...since you've already gotten answers on the new copy, deleting the old one might be the best approach -- but do avoid making the same mistake again.

Comment: Do you also need to remove the commas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.lstrip("$")` to strip the "$" from in front. This avoids removing the first character in the case where your code is fed a salary without a "$" in front"
For example:

```
e.salary = col[2].lstrip("$")
```

BTW, consider storing your salaries at as int's (do everything in cents instead of dollars) because floats are not exact, for example 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3 . Or You could use python's built in [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have realized this, but python does not allow commas in strings when converting into one of the numeric types.

If the data is a string, you can use `translate`. if it's unicode, IIRC there might be some edge cases and `replace` is a better option

```
e.salary = col[2].translate(None, '$,')
e.salary = col[2].replace('$', '').replace(',','')
```

the suggestion to use `col[2].lstrip('$')` above is great BUT you need to replace the `,` in the salary before casting it to float .

```
e.salary = col[2].lstrip('$').replace(',','')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
e.salary = col[2][1:]
```

Comment: This works on one value, but I still need to remove the $ from  one column of salaries which spans 9000 rows. Then I need to parse as a float and call min and max. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why? How is this different from what the OP is doing?